# ¿Como puedo limitar los elementos en una FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Estoy intentado limitar los elementos, en este caso los posts, quiero solo mostrar 4 posts.

**Mi Codigo:**

```
componentDidMount() {
   return fetch(ConfigApp.URL+'json/data_posts.php')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataPosts: responseJson
       }
     })}

render() {
return (
    <FlatList
      data={ this.state.dataPosts }
      renderItem={({item}) => 
            <Image source={{uri: ConfigApp.IMAGESFOLDER+item.post_image}}/>              
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma, seguro que te funciona:

```
componentDidMount() {
  return fetch(ConfigApp.URL+'json/data_posts.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataPosts: responseJson.slice(0,4) //<---- AQUI FILTRAMOS 4 PRIMEROS ELEMENTOS
      }
    })}

render() {
return (
   <FlatList
     data={ this.state.dataPosts }
     renderItem={({item}) => 
           <Image source={{uri: ConfigApp.IMAGESFOLDER+item.post_image}}/>              
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  />
```